# Lex rule to recognize tab and allow white blanks?

Tags: yacc, lex

I am trying to write a lex code to recognize if the string contains a tab and I also want to allow any blank spaces between words.

In my lex file, I write
[  \t] {yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return TAB;}
to recognize tabs. It does recognize tab, but if the given input string contains a white space yacc returns an error. For example my rule gives no error for "x=5" but it does for "x= 5" or "x = 5".
I'd like to write a lex rule that will allow me to recognize 4 consecutive blanks(a tab) and also will allow for one white space.
Thank you.

Comment: If you're trying to implement the offside rule (i.e. a layout-aware language like Python), you only need to capture whitespace at the beginning of a line: `^[ \t]+`. If you just want a rule which only matches tabs use `\t`, plain and simple. Or `\t+` if you want to match several. Please read the [flex docs on patterns](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

Comment: I capture a tab with [ \t] {yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return TAB;}. But now if there is an input that contains any white space, the program expects me to add a tab rule in yacc. For example: I capture a tab with [ \t] {yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return TAB;} and my rule in yacc is IDENTIFIER EQUALSYMBOL INTEGER. If the input is x=5 it accepts but if the input is x = 5 it doesn't accept. I want my program to accept both of them at the same time and if there is a tab I want to capture it.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but generally I agree with rici. Here's some more pointers: Just writing `[ ]` will capture a single space. If you want to catch only groups of 4, write something like `[ ]{4}`. This won't be needed if you really just want to capture indentation. In that case limiting yourself to a beginning of a line is enough. Also, you need a rule that ignores other whitespaces, e.g. `[[:space:]] {}`.

Comment: I am writing a program, a set of rules, that will change a python code to into c++ code. This is why the tabs are important. They are important because I need to catch if/else inconsistencies. Thank you so much for your answer btw!

Comment: @SebSeb: Python only cares about whitespace at the beginning of a line. That's important. Have you read the Flex pattern documentation yet? Check the `^` anchor syntax.